# How to work with product meta field in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have created a custom meta field for blog posts in Shopify. It's of the type `product` and I have chosen `List of products`.

I want to loop through the products and render them using the theme's `product-grid-item` template.

My problem is, that the type of my meta field output is a `string` - not an `array.`

If i try to output the field like this `{{ article.metafields.blog_post.feature_products }}`

I get the following:
`["gid://shopify/Product/8078688583991","gid://shopify/Product/8078688715063","gid://shopify/Product/8078689141047"]`

Which looks like an array, but liquid sees it as a string.

I have tried to loop through it like the following. But nothing happens

```
{% for product_id in article.metafields.blog_post.feature_products %}   
  {{ product_id }} 
{% endfor %}
```

It feels like I'm missing something obvious. It doesn't make sense, that the output is a string.

Does anybody know how to output it like an array? Or how to convert the string to an array - without the quote-marks, brackets and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For metafields that allow multiple values, the list of values is stored in the `value` property of the metafield. Add `.value` at the end of your loop statement.

Note that your `product_id` variable will be a [`product`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product) object. I suggest you rename it to "product". You can then access the id (and other properties) using the dot notation.

```
{% for product in article.metafields.blog_post.feature_products.value %}   
  {{ product.id }} 
{% endfor %}
```